# sudo fab deps_local

Tags: sudo

I executed `sudo fab deps_local` in Ubuntu's terminal and got the following output:

```
[localhost] local: sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Reading http://www.pip-installer.org
Reading http://pip.openplans.org
Best match: pip 1.3.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-    1.3.1.tar.gz#md5=cbb27a191cebc58997c4da8513863153
Processing pip-1.3.1.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-u4gcui/pip-1.3.1/setup.cfg
Running pip-1.3.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-u4gcui/pip-    1.3.1/egg-dist-tmp-_xmcut
warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.txt' found under directory     'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build/_sources'
Adding pip 1.3.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip
[localhost] local: sudo pip install virtualenv
Downloading/unpacking virtualenv
Downloading virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz (2.0MB): 45kB downloaded
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py",     line 139, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-    py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 266, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle,     bundle=self.bundle)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line     1033, in prepare_files
self.unpack_url(url, location, self.is_download)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line     1161, in unpack_url
retval = unpack_http_url(link, location, self.download_cache, self.download_dir)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py",     line 554, in unpack_http_url
download_hash = _download_url(resp, link, temp_location)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.3.1-py2.7.egg/pip/download.py",     line 458, in _download_url
chunk = resp.read(4096)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
data = self._sock.recv(left)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 561, in read
s = self.fp.read(amt)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 380, in read
data = self._sock.recv(left)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241, in recv
return self.read(buflen)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 160, in read
return self._sslobj.read(len)
SSLError: The read operation timed out

Storing complete log in /home/asus/.pip/pip.log

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 2) while executing 'sudo pip        install virtualenv'

Aborting.
asus@ubuntu:~/ADL_LRS$
```

It seems that the code `sudo fab deps_local` did NOT work well. Am I right? If so, what should I do?

Comment: Could you paste your pip.log to paste.ubuntu.com or any other paste site and provide us with the link? I assuem this file holds some information why it failed.

Comment: where is pip.log?

Comment: Did you even read what you posted? `Storing complete log in /home/asus/.pip/pip.log`

Comment: Ok. I pasted the pip.log into paste.ubuntu.com. The link is `http://paste.ubuntu.com/5669707/`

Comment: All this shows is that the computer you were running these commands had issues connecting to `https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz`. There's nothing more to say other than 'connection issues'. Try re-running the command on a later time or include the output of `wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/v/virtualenv/virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz`. I can download this file pretty well, though.

Answer (score 0):

You're just having connection issues.

I don't know what `fab deps_local` is, but the output you provided may be the result of this, I guess. All I see is that

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

resulted in

```
Downloading virtualenv-1.9.1.tar.gz (2.0MB): 45kB downloaded
[...]
SSLError: The read operation timed out
```

So check your network connection, or the target website may be down for maintenance.

Comment: Neither my connection has problem nor the target website has problem. I'm sure about that.

Comment: Well, I'm sure about that it downloaded 45kB and then it failed. There's nothing more to tell from here, I'm afraid.

Comment: Could you give me a solution, please. Thank you.